# Error message using amsart class with parskip package

Tags: amsart, parskip

I am trying to use Macvim combined with the Vimlatex package. It seems that
when I use the amsart article class combined with the parskip package gives me an error. When I use TexShop for example, the document compiles without any errors. I also compiled the document using the terminal, once again no problems. It only occurs when I compile my .tex document using the ,ll command from within vim. Here is the error message I get:

```
**Error Message**:/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/parskip/parskip.sty|| LaTeX Warning: Command \@starttoc  has changed. Check if current package is valid.
```

I am using Macvim 7.4 on Max OS X, Mavericks, if that's important. Macvim automatically takes me to the parskip.sty as well and I can't even get back to my original editing session. This is so frustrating. I am fairly new to Vim btw :)

Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: You can't use `parskip` with `amsart` unless you avoid using `\tableofcontents`, `\listoffigures` and `\listoftables`: the package redefines `\@starttoc` in a way that doesn't please `amsart`. If you don't use those commands, there should be no problem. But don't use `parskip`: the normal paragraph indentation has revealed a good typographic device for several centuries; no indentation and paragraph separation used to be fashionable for some time in the first half of the 20th century, but good typographers avoid it.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I'll use this best practice from now on.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you. A suggestion: Do us a favour and change your username to something more telling than "user1234".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `\parskip` package tries to avoid applying a nonzero parskip in the table of contents; to this effect it checks whether the macro `\@starttoc` has the same meaning as in the LaTeX kernel, in order to modify it.

The `amsart` class indeed changes the meaning of `\@starttoc`, because it uses a slightly different approach for typesetting the table of contents and similar lists. So the check performed by `parskip` with `\CheckCommand` fails and an error is raised.

Solution: don't use `parskip` together with `amsart`. The class follows the AMS editorial guidelines, which (happily) don't allow vertical separation between paragraphs.

Of course “happily” is related to my opinion that this vertical separation is a horrible typographical device in books and journals. It makes white strips that destroy the uniformity of a page; if the paragraphs are short, the effect is even worse.

<sub>**Imporant note:** not all black and white stripes are bad</sub>

[image]