# Margin comment throwing "underfull \hbox" error

Tags: marginpar

So first off, let me show you a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{mycol}{rgb}{0,0.5,0}
\newcommand\marginComment[1]{\marginpar{\hsize1.7cm\tiny\color{mycol}C: {#1}}}

\begin{document}

\marginComment{No, this really shouldn't fail!}
\end{document}
```

When I run this on TexMaker 4.3 I get the following error:

```
Badbox line 9 Underfull \hbox (badness 4636) in paragraph at lines 9--9
```

The weirdest part is that if I edit the words sometimes I don't get the error at all. So my assumption is that it's because of the length or something. Is there anyway to make it so that this error doesn't happen and/or a way around it if I'm making a mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "underfull \hbox" arises because too much stretching of the interword space on the second of three lines of the marginpar box -- between "eally" and "shouldn't" is required to achieve full justification. To remedy this situation, I suggest you include the following instruction in the preamble:

```
\usepackage[raggedrightboxes]{ragged2e}
```

This will set up raggedright typesetting (with hyphenation permitted) in all `\marginpar`s, `minipage`s, `\parbox`es, and p-columns of `tabular`s and `array`s in your document.

The result of a full MWE (with the color changed to blue for ease of readability):

[image]

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage[raggedrightboxes]{ragged2e}
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{mycol}{rgb}{0,0,1}
\newcommand\marginComment[1]{\marginpar{\hsize1.7cm\tiny\color{mycol}C: {#1}}}

\begin{document}
\marginComment{No, this really shouldn't fail!}
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*: If you need `\RaggedRight` only in `\marginpar`s, but not in `minipage`s, `\parbox`es, and p-columns of `tabular`s and `array`s, you could (a) load the `ragged2e` package *without* the `raggedrightboxes` option and (b) (re)define your `\marginComment` macro as follows:

```
\newcommand\marginComment[1]{\marginpar{\RaggedRight\hsize1.7cm\tiny\color{mycol}C: {#1}}}
```

As a side-benefit of this method, you will no longer be bothered by cryptic "Command \@arrayparboxrestore has changed." warning messages. :-)

Comment: Although that does remove the problem, I now get "Command \@arrayparboxrestore has changed." using your MWE. =/

Comment: @AramPapazian - That's a warning message (not an error message!) you can blissfully ignore. Kudos, though, for actually looking at the output of the compilation log!

Comment: Yeah, but I don't like warnings either lol I like having a nice empty log =) (Don't most people look at compilation logs? o_O) Is the warning due to the package itself being somehow out of date or something like that? Or is there anyway around it? I did a quick google search, but I didn't see the problem anywhere.

Comment: @AramPapazian - For what it's worth, I've been using the `ragged2e` package for years in my own work, and I've learned to live with this message -- more specifically, to ignore it. :-) I truly have no idea why it's even being generated.

Comment: Ok, so after some more research I found the following: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/174073/error-message-using-amsart-class-with-parskip-package    I imagine the same (or similar) thing is happening here since the document class is amsart. I switched to an article documentclass and the error went away so I assume that to be a fairly accurate assessment. So seems like, as you said, I'll just have to live with the error message =) Thanks for the information though!

Comment: @AramPapazian - I've posted an addendum with a second solution: simply redefine your `\marginComment` macro to include a `\RaggedRight` directive.

Comment: Slick. Awesome! That's perfect. Thanks a bajillion.

Answer (score 1):

If you can, use `marginnote` package and `\marginnote` instead of `\marginpar`.

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\definecolor{mycol}{rgb}{0,0.5,0}
\newcommand\marginComment[1]{\marginnote{\hsize1.7cm\tiny\color{mycol}C: {#1}}}

\begin{document}

\marginComment{No, this really shouldn't fail!}
\end{document}
```

[image]