# LaTeX Warning: Command \@arrayparboxrestore has changed

Tags: warnings, ragged2e

Hey so this error message `LaTeX Warning: Command \@arrayparboxrestore  has changed.` manifests up when I use `\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}` but the error does not manifest whenever I comment out that line, what is `\@arrayparboxrestore` and what can I do with this error since it seems to have changed?

Here is all the packages I have called in just in case it may have something to do with them as well

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{EB Garamond}

\usepackage{listings}

\usepackage{setspace}
\singlespacing
\setlength{\parskip}{\baselineskip}

\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear,citestyle=apa]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{ref.bib}
```

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/271292/margin-comment-throwing-underfull-hbox-error#comment651490_271295

Comment: If I extend the posted preamble to a short example document I can not reproduce warning message you mention. Would it be possible to add a `\begin{document}...\end{document}` with some dummy content to the MWE so that it becomes a fully self-contained example document that reproduces the warning? (You may also want to remove the call to `biblatex` for the example if it is not required to reproduce the issue.)

Comment: Completely unrelated: `style=authoryear,citestyle=apa` is a bit of a weird combination. Usually the `apa` citation style should be used together with the bibliography style (i.e. you should only have `style=apa` for full APA style), I don't think the two are designed to be used separately (that is not to say that using them separately will result in an error, but you can not expect that everything works smoothly). For the most part `style=authoryear,citestyle=apa` is not a big departure from `style=authoryear`, so I definitely recommend dropping `citestyle=apa` here.

Comment: Is your system up-to-date?

Comment: That bug is fixed in the latest version 2.2 of ragged2e, currently only available from Gitlab: https://gitlab.com/hagenbuch/ragged2e

Comment: @MartinSchröder which bug? I don't get the message if I extend the example code. (Btw: did you get my mail a few days ago?).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Got your mail. https://gitlab.com/hagenbuch/ragged2e/commit/5609abd56909e531401521bc9610a6c4b41af96a