# amsart table of contents: the 'content' header appears after the table

Tags: table-of-contents, amsart

I am using the amsart document, and simply typed in

```
\tableofcontents
```

But in the output, the header **Contents** appears at the end of the table:

> 1. section 1
> 2. section 2
> 3. ...
>
> Contents

I believe normally it would be

> Contents
>
> 1. section 1
> 2. section 2
> 3. ...

Does anyone know how to change this?

**Update:**

The code is simply:

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{amsfonts,latexsym,amsthm,amssymb,amsmath,amscd,euscript}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
    \usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,decorations.markings}
\usepackage{MnSymbol,wasysym}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{hyperref}
    \hypersetup{colorlinks=true,citecolor=blue,urlcolor 
=black,linkbordercolor={1 0 0}}
\usepackage[left=1in,right=1in,top=1.3in,bottom=1.3in]{geometry}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{etoolbox}



\title{your title}
\author{the author}
\begin{document}
\begin{abstract} 
    abstract here
\end{abstract}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\section{section 1}
\section{section 2}
\end{document}
```

where I included all packages I'm using. Below is what the code produced.
[image]
Thanks a lot!

**Update 2**

After some troubleshooting, I now know that it's because of the `\usepackage{parskip}`. Here's what it looks like if I comment out `\usepackage{parskip}`.
[image: sample2]

Does anyone know how to get the contents back to normal while using this package?

Comment: The table of contents appears where you place the command `\tableofcontents`. It should be just after `\maketitle`.

Comment: @egreg it is right after \maketitle.

Comment: Please, add an example of code.

Comment: @egreg, It's probably caused by the `\usepackage{parskip}`, see the updates. Thank you.

Comment: I tried your example; apart from the error about `cleveref` that should be called *after* `hyperref`, I get no surprise.

Comment: @egreg. That was a typo, I copied things in the wrong order. Don't you get something looks like the first picture?

Comment: No, I get the equivalent of your second picture (even not removing `parskip`)

Comment: I got the same problem as you, it seems to be a problem between parskip and amsart. Did you solve it? Maybe one option is to update the TeXLive distribution (I have the 2015 version...)

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/174073/error-message-using-amsart-class-with-parskip-package